# Jenkins ssh-agent Host key verification failed

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am trying this pipeline script

```
   stage('Deploy') {
      steps {
        container('docker') {
            sshagent (credentials: ['sshsupersecret_key']){
                sh 'git clone git@bitbucket.org:org_name/appconfigs.git'
            }
```

When trying to clone the git repo , I am getting `Host key verification failed.` . I am using the right key as it's the same key which jenkins is using to clone the application code in the same pipeline . Access key has been already added to the repo of bitbucket .

If I try this workaround it's working ,

```
steps {
        container('docker') {
script {
withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: "sshsupersecret_key", keyFileVariable: 'keyfile')]) {
                sh """ 
                mkdir ~/.ssh
                chmod 700 ~/.ssh
                cp ${keyfile} ~/.ssh/id_rsa
                chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
                cp ${keyfile} ~/.ssh/id_rsa
                ssh-keyscan bitbucket.org >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
                git clone git@bitbucket.org:org_name/appconfigs.git
                """
                }
            }
```

If I am already providing the credentials in first method , why it's not able to authenticate ?
I am running Jenkins on Kubernetes.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try adding this

```
echo "Host *" > ~/.ssh/config
echo " StrictHostKeyChecking no" >> ~/.ssh/config
```